# ClojureScript interop

Tags: clojure, interop, clojurescript

I am trying to find out how to access Javascript objects properties in ClojureScript. If I know in advance the name of the property, that is easy. To get `foo.bar` I just do

```
(.-bar foo)
```

> Is there a way to access a property whose name is known only at runtime? I am looking for the equivalent of the JS syntax `foo[dynamicBar]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use aget / aset to access properties known only at runtime.

```
;; Use clj->js to convert clj(s) map to javascript.
;; Note the #js {:bar 100} reader literal indicating a js map.

cljs.user> (def foo (clj->js {:bar 100}))
#js {:bar 100}
cljs.user> (.-bar foo) 
100
cljs.user> (aget foo "bar")
100
cljs.user> (aset foo "baz" 200)
200
cljs.user> (.-baz foo) 
200
```

Comment: One might want to know that it is (at least today) possible to use `(js-obj "bar" 100)`, avoiding the need of js*.

Answer (score 1):

Using string names may be also important in case when you want to take advantage of :optimizations :advanced compiler mode, but you don't have externs file covering your code.

See David Nolen's example using `goog.object.get`:
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Dependencies#using-string-names

While `aget` works. This method was originally supposed to provide you access to array elements, not properties of js objects in general. goog.object's get method is a better way to communicate your intent.

Here are the implementations of both methods:
https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/1b8a893271d790626b5cd652b922675c987f106d/closure/goog/object/object.js#L403

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/d2d031605b1ad552077218c8f445868653c01744/src/main/clojure/cljs/core.cljc#L942

As you can see, `(aget o key)`generates javascript code `o[key]` directly, but goog.object.get calls a method which first checks if the key is present in o.

Comment: IMHO using goog.object.get directly is an anti-pattern in clojurescript.  It makes for uglier code.  If the check is wanted it is easy enough to put in without this.  If it is generally wanted then arguably aget should do that or have an optional parameter to do that.  Or one can simply roll one's own.  Most anything is preferable to putting ugly closure full names all over the place.