# How to get data from events with jayq in Clojurescript?

Tags: jquery, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to get modifer key data from an event with jayq (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379955/841431)).

This works just fine

```
(delegate $body note-list-item :click
      (fn [e]
        (.preventDefault e)
        (js/alert "clicked!")))
```

But this doesn't.

```
(delegate $body note-list-item :click
      (fn [e]
        (.preventDefault e)
        (if (.metaKey e)
          (js/alert "meta clicked")
          (js/alert "no meta"))))
```

The Javascript console in Chrome gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'metaKey' of object #<Object> is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And then I immediately figured it out, of course. `metaKey` is a property of the object, not a method. In Clojurescript you get it with `(.-metaKey e)` (note the dash). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861485/clojurescript-interop) for more details.